# Using UNNEST for a column with (n) values duplicates all values for (n) rows

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a single record with column (type) containing an array of values, e.g. [Map,Table,Pie]

Using Athena I need to to flatten this record into 3 separate records each with one value from the array in the (type) column.

```
SELECT type
FROM
athenadb.table,
UNNEST(type) as charttyp
```

This is the result of this query, three identical records.

```
1 [Map, Pie, Table]
2 [Map, Pie, Table] 
3 [Map, Pie, Table]
```

What am I missing here ? Clearly on one hand it recognizes the array length = 3 but does not parse the array elements...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ntype
FROM
athenadb.table,
UNNEST(type) as t(ntype)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing specifying the alias for column and using it in the resulting `select` as described in [the documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) ([trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) one):

```sql
SELECT flattened_type
FROM athenadb.table,
UNNEST(type) as t(flattened_type)
```